# How to catch sdbus::Error exception in c++?

Tags: java, c++, error-handling, java-native-interface, try-catch

I'm new in c++. I'm trying to process some errors which can occurs in my java application with jni. This is my try/catch block:

```
   std::future<lib::LibVector> libVectorFuture;
      
            try {
              libVectorFuture = some::lib::getVector(param1, param2);
          } catch (...) {
              // report problem back to Java.
              jclass Exception = env->FindClass("com/my/MyClientException");
              env->ThrowNew(Exception, "Unable to get result from native getVector(String p1, String p2) method!");
          }

lib::LibVector vector = libVectorFuture.get();

// here I'm using vector
```

It works when I use valid params (param1, param2). But when I'm using invalid parameters I get error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sdbus::Error'

and some other text. Also, the application stopped. As I understand in the catch block I can catch any error, but it is not happening. Why? And how to catch any error?

Comment: Note that `ThrowNew` does not exit the current C++ function, so it just continues. Are you sure the error is not thrown by `libVectorFuture.get()`?

Comment: Yes, you right. Error throwed in libVectorFuture.get(). When I moved it to try section my application doesn't throwed java Exception and as I see method continue works. As I understand it is required to add return before ThrowNew to trow exception. But my method return object, not jint which returns return ThrowNew.  How I can return java exception as object?

Comment: If you throw an exception you should not need to return anything sensible. Just return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I wrote a solution. Thanks for your replies.

```
     std::future<lib::LibVector> libVectorFuture;
  
        try {
          libVectorFuture = some::lib::getVector(param1, param2);
          lib::LibVector vector = libVectorFuture.get(); // here I get error
      } catch (...) {
          // report problem back to Java.
          jclass Exception = env->FindClass("com/my/MyClientException");
          env->ThrowNew(Exception, "Unable to get result from native getVector(String p1, String p2) method!");
       return nullptr;
      }
```